# Handlebars template with subexpresion

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am having trouble trying to get a subexpression in handlebars.
I have this object

```
{
  vehicles:{
    air:"airplane",
    water:"boat",
    land:"cars\nvans",
  }
}
```

I have this helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('split', function(str, ch) {
    if (!str) return '';
    if (typeof ch !== 'string') ch = /\n/;
    return str.split(ch).map(function(splitted) {
    splitted.trim();
});
});
```

I would like to have an output like this

```
air/airplane
water/boat
land/cars
land/vans
```

With this template

```
{{#each vehicles}}
    {{#each (split this)}}
        {{../key}}/{{{this}}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I debugged and the `split` helpers get the values correctly, i think it has to be something with the scope of my this

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found my issue, the way to access the `key` of my object in the nested `#each` was not `../@key` it turns out that it should be `@../key`